# why gradle publish is running last task

Tags: gradle

Below are relevant build.gradle snippets

```
version = '0.0.25-SNAPSHOT'
publishing {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }

    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = group
            artifactId = 'xyz-abc'
            version = version
            from components.java
        }
    }
}

task incrementSnapshotVersion {
    String jVersion = version
    int snapshotSuffixBegin = jVersion.lastIndexOf('-')
    String currentMinor = jVersion.substring(jVersion.lastIndexOf('.') + 1, snapshotSuffixBegin)
    String updatedMinor = (Integer.parseInt(currentMinor) + 1).toString()
    String major = jVersion.substring(0, jVersion.lastIndexOf(currentMinor))
    String newVersion = major + updatedMinor + "-SNAPSHOT"
    String s = buildFile.getText().replaceFirst("version = '$jVersion'", "version = '" + newVersion + "'")
    buildFile.setText(s)
}
```

On running below command, 
`/home/user/gradle-5.1.1/bin/gradle clean build`, the `incrementSnapshotVersion` task is also being run and the version is updated unexpectedly.
Also tried `-x incrementSnapshotVersion` but still the version would increase in file, however, on removing the `incrementSnapshotVersion` from build.gradle, version remains as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, the version will be increased in the configuration phase, that's why everytime you run a command, the version is increased.

You have to put that behavior in the task's action.

In this way, only when you'll execute the task with `./gradlew incrementSnapshotVersion` or you'll execute a task which **depends on** OR **is finalized by** your task, the version will be increased.

```
task incrementSnapshotVersion {
    doFirst {
        String jVersion = version
        int snapshotSuffixBegin = jVersion.lastIndexOf('-')
        String currentMinor = jVersion.substring(jVersion.lastIndexOf('.') + 1, snapshotSuffixBegin)
        String updatedMinor = (Integer.parseInt(currentMinor) + 1).toString()
        String major = jVersion.substring(0, jVersion.lastIndexOf(currentMinor))
        String newVersion = major + updatedMinor + "-SNAPSHOT"
        String s = buildFile.getText().replaceFirst("version = '$jVersion'", "version = '" + newVersion + "'")
        buildFile.setText(s)
    }
}
```